# How to animate a UIImage constraints in Swift 4

Tags: ios, animation, uiimage, constraints, swift4

I am making a card app and I need to make an animation so that a card would change its constraints to move to another place. How would I do this for a UIImage.

Comment: You can change the leading/trailing constant value of UIImage and then call `UIView.animateWithDuration(duration){ self.view.layoutIfNeeded() }`. Do some research please. You need to learn it properly instead of just asking it here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to drag and drop your constraint into your view controller, to make an outlet. The same way you are doing it with `UIImageView` or `UITableView`, etc.

Actually, for those who have watched WWDC (2014 I guess), Apple have explained how to animate UI in the proper way.

Firstly, you have to call `layoutIfNeeded()` method to make sure that everything on your view have laid out. After you can change your constraint and right after that in your animation block you call `layoutIfNeeded()` method to layout your constraint with the new value.

So code should look like that:

```
view.layoutIfNeeded() // to make sure your view have laid out

self.constraint.constant = //change your constant to any value

UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
   self.view.layoutIfNeeded() //layout your constraint with the new value
}
```

Comment: What if you made your constraint programmatically. How could you change it. I tried doing something like: copyImages.imageViewBottom.layoutIfNeeded()                                                               
self.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true                    

Though it's not working

Answer (score 1):

Hook the leading , trailing , CenterX OR CenterY constraint of the UIImageView and do this

```
self.imageLeadCon.constant = // value

UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0 ,  animations: {

   self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    // animation
}, completion: { _ in

    // completion
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing `UIImage` with `UIImageView`. The first one is the image's data representation, the second one is the View that displays the `UIImage`.

So I guess you want to move around the `UIImageView`. To do that obtain a reference to the constraints (e.g. by ctrl-dragging from the constraint in the storyboard to your `UIViewController` instance).

After that you can update the constraint in an animation block like here:

```
// Make sure the view is laid out as Mischanya Schtrigel stated
self.view.layoutIfNeeded() 
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) { // duration in seconds
    myConstraint.constant = 50 // update your constraint here
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Contrary to the other answers, I like putting the constraint changes in the animation closure to make it more clear what is going to be animated.